# RES_NOT_FOUND after login using JAAS

Tags: jsf, tomcat7, jaas

I am using JAAS to authenticate users accessing the protected area of my web application. The login page looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; UTF-8" />
    <title>Test</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <ui:composition template="template/common/commonLayout.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="content">
            <form name="loginForm" method="post" action="j_security_check">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">Login to the your application:</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Select something:</td>
                        <td><h:selectOneMenu>
                                <f:selectItems value="#{loginScreenBean.listSomething}" />
                            </h:selectOneMenu><br /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Name:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="j_username" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Password:</td>
                        <td><input type="password" name="j_password" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Go" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</h:body>
</html>
```

My web-xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>patchit</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>test.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <security-role>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
  </security-role>
  <security-constraint>
    <display-name>Example Security Constraint</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Protected Area</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/protected/*</url-pattern>
      <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
      <http-method>GET</http-method>
      <http-method>POST</http-method>
      <http-method>PUT</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
  <login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>Example Form-Based Authentication Area</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
      <form-login-page>/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
      <form-error-page>/login-error.xhtml</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
  </login-config>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
</web-app>
```

my jaas config looks like this:

```
CustomLogin {
    de.kungfuzius.test.security.SimpleLoginModule
    sufficient;
};
```

so when I open a page in the protected area like contextpath/protected/test.xhtml I am presented the login.xhtml with the login form. Once I hit the submit button the user is authenticated, but instead of being forwarded/redirected to the initially requested page I am redirected to contextpath/protected/RES_NOT_FOUND. To check if the user is really authenticated I tried to access contextpath/protected/test.xhtml again at it worked.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

wow, interesting behavior. I had a look at the requests using fiddler and I found a request to context/protected/RES_NOT_FOUND. This request came from a css file which was referenced in my template, but did not exist yet.

When I remove this reference to the style sheet it works!!!